# Migrating stats from Wordpress.com blog to self-hosted Wordpress.org blog

Tags: migration, statistics

I'm currently trying to migrate the wordpress.com stats over to a self-hosted wordpress.org blog for a client.  Migrating databases and everything else is absolutely no problem, I just haven't been able to find any definitive information on whether or not this is possible.  Could anyone point me in the right direction to getting this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but [requires help from an official WordPress support person](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/transfer-of-my-stats-and-followers-to-self-hosted?replies=22#post-1964830) (aka "Happiness Engineer") to do it:

> As for stats, they can also be moved, but staff have to take care of that. Once you have Jetpack installed on the new WordPress.ORG install, post the relevant URLs in this forum thread and then add the "modlook" tag n the column on the right.

** Note: "WordPress.ORG" above really means "self-hosted" site. That's a common misnomer that was introduced earlier in the quoted thread.*

So to do it from start to finish:

1. Migrate your site to a self-hosted install as much as you can.
2. Install the [Jetpack plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack) and connect it to a WordPress.com account. (I don't know if it helps if it's the one associated with your WordPress.com site. It can't hurt.)
3. Open a [new WordPress.com support thread](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/?new=1). Tag it "modlook" and request that they move your stats to your new domain. Make sure to provide your old WordPress.com site and your new self-hosted domain.

Alternately, you can always use the [paid "Guided Transfer"](http://en.support.wordpress.com/guided-transfer/) that also includes moving stats.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and straight forward answer.  Just what I needed to know.

I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but I will revisit this thread when I do.  Thanks again.

Comment: If you import from local or http URL, its not import because wordpress.com only allow to https url for media export and import to your WordPress.